# "Reschedule" as a noun

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Is it correct to use "reschedule" as a noun?

> We apologize for the *reschedule*.

No dictionary defines the word as a noun. Yet, the sentence above is from a test writing assignment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched "The Corpus of Contemporary American English", a collection of a billion or so words from 1990 to 2019, for "the reschedule" and "a reschedule". The search had 2 results with "the" and 3 with "a", that is, not many at all.
It's completely understandable, but it might be better to stick with "rescheduling".

You can try this yourself:
[COCA search](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=9)

Comment: Thank you! I entirely agree.